# Download FPR files from SSC Fortify

Tags: security, fortify

I want to download the FPR file from SSC center from Fortify Scan. Is there a way that i can download the FPR file the same way i can upload the FPR file to SSC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the command line, you can only download the **latest** fpr file which has been uploaded for a project version, using the `downloadFPR` command:

```
$ fortifyclient downloadFPR -file result.fpr -url http://sscserver:8080/ssc/ -authtoken 123456789-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc -project "My Project" -version "0.1"
```

All FPR files which have been uploaded are available for download in the web UI at the "Artifacts" tab of each project version:

- On the start page, select the "Projects" tab
- Select a project version and press the "View details" button
- Select the "Artifacts" tab for this project version

This opens a list of the Analysis results (the results which have been uploaded so far). Select the one you need and press the "Download" button to download the corresponding `.fpr` file.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas that worked. For others who are trying to do this just a note a new token needs to be generated for Download its not same as Upload token even for same user.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the FPR file using three simple steps.

1. Login to SSC portal.
2. Choose the project -> go to Artifact.
3. Click on Application file.